# Vanil Javascript .animate() hamburger menu disappears after completion

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, animation

I have an Svg hamburger menu which i'm using to target an event listener,
this invokes the javascript .animate() api & brings the menu pane in from the left,
however when the animation is completed it dissapears(it does not return to it's original position), it just vanishes. I would like it to stay put & then set-up a seperate function to fade it out or slide back.

My HTML is here:

```
<svg>`Hamburger Code`</svg>

<section id="menuPane" class="lftMenu"
         style="position:absolute;
                left:-888px;
                z-index:18;">
    <div class="test">

    </div>
    <div class="tst2">

    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS is here:

```
    .test{
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        width:calc(27vw - 7vmax);
        height:calc(55vh + 4.8vmin);
        top:48.4px; left:8px;
        background-image:linear-gradient(-48deg,green,yellow);
        border-radius:8.2px;
        z-index:19;
        }
    .test:before{
        content:"";
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        width:inherit; height:inherit;
        filter:opacity(0.55) hue-rotate(120deg);
        background-image:radial-gradient(ellipse at top,blue,green);
        border:solid inset 28px transparent;
        border-radius:8.2px;
        z-index:20;
        }
    .tst2{
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:48.4px; left:8px;
        width:calc(27vw - 7vmax); height:calc(55vh + 4.8vmin);
        background-image:url('GalvPlt1.jpg');
        background-size:contain;
        filter:opacity(0.2);
        border-radius:8.2px;
        z-index:21;
        }
    .tst2:hover{
        filter:hue-rotate(208deg) opacity(0.44);
        }
```

My Javascript is here:

```
            const menu_pane = document.getElementById("menuPane");

            //UiContr.animate([
                // Animate opacity to fade in during page load.
                //])

        let Elem = document.getElementById("Elem");      // This El is the svg box above the menu pane.
            Elem.style.position = "absolute";
            //Elem.style.willChange = "auto";
            Elem.animate({
                 opacity: ['1', '0.224', '1', '0.498', '1'],
                 filter: ['hue-rotate(0deg)', 'hue-rotate(-72deg)', 'hue-rotate(0deg)']
                 // borderRadius: ['8px', '14px']
                    },{ duration: 4864,
                        easing: 'ease-in-out',
                        iterations:7800
                        // 0.1 hours = 360,000 ms...
                        // fill: 'reverse'
            });

            Elem.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
                // menu.style.animationFillMode = 'forwards';
                menu_pane.animate({
                    left: ['-888px','8px']
                },{ duration: 600,
                    easing: 'ease-in-out',
                    iterations:1,
                    // fill: forwards,
                });/*.then(
                menu_pane.style.left = "8px";
                );*/
            });
```

These are sitting ontop of 3 layered Canvases, one buffer, one menu & the main game window.
All with lower z-index values. I can't figure out where its going to...
I tried this:

`menu.style.animationFillMode = 'forwards';`

*.tried this in the CSS file aswell none camel case.[nope nothing.]

As a similar question stated animations always return to there initial state.
but that would mean it would slide back to the left, not just pop of the screen & down the pub.. & I also tried chaining a .then() on the end, but this failed also..

Also as an Aside the tutorial I watched, used fill: forwards, reverse, or both & also infinity for iterations as options of .animate() but now I trying these none are being recognised or working.
**>.... Partially Solved, Infinity needed Capitolized first letter.**

Also, Which is the best way to write these out of the following 2 methods;

Youtube Tutorial Version is:

```
    .animate({property:['from','to']},{',' seperated options});
```

MDN version is:

```
    .animate([{Property: 'from'},{Property: 'to'}],{',' seperated options});
```

both of these examples work & animate the same, achieveing about 58fps, but is there a "Correct" or Optimal way to write this.
I would lean more towards the MDN version being more 'Correct' or optimal,
but is there any reason for the two variants, which should I choose?
Although the MDN version you have to write the property name multiple times & with complex, multi parameter animations that might end up being quite a bit more code.? any inputs:

This is the example version of V. Javascript .animate() function.

```
    document.getElementById("tunnel").animate([
          // keyframes
           { transform: 'translateY(0px)' }, 
           { transform: 'translateY(-300px)' }
    ], { 
          // timing options
             duration: 1000,
             iterations: Infinity
    });
```

Thanks in advance any who comments or answers..